# creating a custom TFDS dataset

Tags: tensorflow, dataset, tensorflow-datasets, trax

I would like to create a custom tensorflow dataset for summarization task. I have a set of reports with three gold summaries for every report. All the data is in (.txt) format.
I would like to create a TFDS where the key is the report and the value is the summary. So I will have this format:
(report1 , summary11) (report1 , summary12) (report1 , summary13) (report2 , summary21) (report2 , summary22) (report2 , summary23)

Is there any solution that helps me achieve this task. I checked the official documentation on the tensorflow website and it wasn't useful for me.

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

A custom iterator for traversing through data files can be achieved through the generators. As tf datasets retrieves input from generator you could modify the generator code to return the results

```
def generator(tuples):
   for tuple in tuples:
      yield tuple[1]
```